# PostgreSQL: get all json object values per row

Tags: postgresql

I have a `games` table with `players` row. The `players` column is a jsonb in the form of:
`{"digit": [id, id, id, ...], ...}`:

```
select id, players from games;
 id  |           players           
-----+-----------------------------
 236 | {"10": [27, 23, 25]}
 238 | {"7": [22]}
 239 | {"1": [], "2": [], "3": []}
 237 | {"1": []}
```

I would like, for each game id (row) have an array of ids, something like this:

```
  id       just_arrays
-----+-----------------------------
 236 | [27, 23, 25]
 238 | [22]
 239 | []
 237 | []
```

I would then like to build a document where ids will be changed to player's names (which I have in user table):

```
  id              document
-----+-----------------------------
 236 | Player Name1 Player Name2 Player Name3
 238 | Player Name4
 239 | 
 237 |
```

How I can achieve that? I've tried something with `jsonb_each()` but without luck.

Comment: in value `{"10": [27, 23, 25]}` what is the significance of `"10"`. whether it is fixed or any logic is there

Comment: Just a name of the play court (mostly a number). I do not need this key in this context. It is not important.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well I have structure like this at the moment.
The version is PostgreSQL 13.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JSON path function for this:

```
select id, jsonb_path_query_array(players, '$.*[*]') as players.
from games
```

If you need to join that result to another table you need to first unnest the arrays, then join to that result and aggregate back:

```
select g.id, string_agg(u.name, ' ')
from games g
  left join jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(players, '$.*[*]')) as gp(pid) on true
  left join users u on u.id = gp.pid::int
group by g.id
order by g.id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7da9a20d111217c37126f5170121a22c)